# how to give alias to field with custom comments while executing select query in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT office_nameh
              , office_code
              , ddo_code
              , present_post_ac as ac_code 
                  {here i want to provide my custom comments}
              , emp_catg
           FROM employee_data 
          WHERE 1
```

Suppose I have a table where I have given comments to field/column

now I want to give an alias to a column name and comment

office_nameh        |office_code|ddo_code|ac_code   |emp_catg
Office Name in Hindi|Office Code|DDO code|my comment|Employee Catg

Comment: You mean something like `SELECT ..., 'this is my comment' AS my_comment FROM ...`?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with...

```
SELECT DISTINCT office_nameh
              , office_code
              , ddo_code
              , present_post_ac ac_code
              , 'my comments here' custom_comments
              , emp_catg
           FROM employee_data 
          WHERE 1
```

Comment: I want to give custom comment to column name alias